# Why DATA is COPIED and not MOVED while loading data from local filesystem Hive hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

When we use following command:

```
Load data local inpath "mypath"
```

why the data is copied from local filesystem into HDFS and not moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are moving data between 2 different file systems (sh + HDFS) this cannot be a metadata operation as in non-local load. 
The data itself should be copied.
Theoretically this command could also initiate a deletion command of the source file, but what for?